# Why does OBJECT_ID return NULL in a computed column?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, tempdb

I'm trying to produce a usage report for some stored procedures in my database. The view view [sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280701%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) contains some of what I need, so I decided to start here.

SQL Server keys procedure metadata by object ID. I know only the procedure names, so first I have to map the names to IDs using the [OBJECT_ID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190328%28v=sql.100%29.aspx/css) function.

There are several procedures to check, so I want to put their names in a temp table before processing them.

I thought it would be cute to get the object id from a computed column in the temp table, so I created a table like this:

```
USE msdb;
GO

CREATE TABLE #procs (
  name SYSNAME,
  [object_id] AS OBJECT_ID(name)
);

INSERT INTO #procs (name) VALUES ('dbo.sp_send_dbmail');
INSERT INTO #procs (name) VALUES ('dbo.sp_add_job');
INSERT INTO #procs (name) VALUES ('dbo.sp_start_job');
```

With that table in place, the obvious way to get the execution counts looked like this:

```
SELECT #procs.name, execution_count
FROM sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats AS procstats
INNER JOIN #procs ON #procs.[object_id] = procstats.[object_id]
ORDER BY execution_count DESC;
```

But it returns an empty result set!

This query shows why the result set is empty:

```
SELECT name, [object_id]
FROM #procs;
```

The object_id column is NULL, so an inner join will produce no rows:

```
name                 object_id
-------------------- -----------
dbo.sp_send_dbmail   NULL
dbo.sp_add_job       NULL
dbo.sp_start_job     NULL
```

It's not that computed columns are broken for temp tables. If I add a computed column to reverse the name, it produces the correct value when I select from it:

```
ALTER TABLE #procs ADD reverse_name AS REVERSE(name);

SELECT name, [object_id], reverse_name
FROM #procs;
```

Result:

```
name                 object_id   reverse_name
-------------------- ----------- ---------------------
dbo.sp_send_dbmail   NULL        liambd_dnes_ps.obd
dbo.sp_add_job       NULL        boj_dda_ps.obd
dbo.sp_start_job     NULL        boj_trats_ps.obd
```

Why does OBJECT_ID return NULL here?

Comment: you are doing it incorrectly. From BOL (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186301.aspx) `By default, the SQL Server Database Engine assumes that object_id is in the context of the current database. A query that references an object_id in another database returns NULL or incorrect results.`

Comment: @Kin that's true, but since he issues a `USE` command, it might not be altogether intuitive from the docs why the "current database context" is not msdb.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A metadata function mentioned in a computed column in a `#temp` table is going to reference `tempdb.sys.objects`, not `yourdatabase.sys.objects`, since the table is created in `tempdb`. Try adding the database prefix to the insert, and that will make `OBJECT_ID` go find it in the right place:

```
CREATE TABLE #procs (
  name SYSNAME,
  [object_id] AS OBJECT_ID(name)
);

INSERT INTO #procs (name) VALUES ('dbo.sp_send_dbmail');
INSERT INTO #procs (name) VALUES ('msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail');

SELECT name, [object_id] FROM #procs;
```

Results:

```
dbo.sp_send_dbmail          NULL
msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail     283148054
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem. but I think in the end I would avoid using computed columns entirely. See my [comment](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/51317/why-does-object-id-return-null-in-a-computed-column#comment93609_51320) on Remus' answer.

Comment: @IainElder whether you use a computed column or not doesn't matter, if you're not in msdb when you insert the value, if you try to derive object_ID() at that time, it will produce NULL for the same reasons. Another important thing to note is that, for user objects, if you store the object_id(), it could change (drop/create).

Answer (score 3):

You are doing overly overly overly complicated something trivial. Remove the computed column, insert `OBJECT_ID` explicitly.

What happens is that you're lossing control over *where* is `OBJECT_ID` evaluated (in which database context). `OBJECT_ID` will return different values, for same name, in different DBS, or may return NULL for names that do not match current execution context (db). By adding the evaluation onto a `#temp` table you can't be sure *where* does the evaluation occur. Is it in `tempdb`? in `msdb`? In current db? Well, it looks like is not where you expected it to be, that's sure...

Ditch the fancy cleverness, stick to KISS.

Next, fix your `` `JOIN #procs ON #procs.[object_id] = procstats.[object_id] ``, as is incorrect. You need to join on `object_id` **and** `database_id`.

Comment: I've gone right off computed columns. In my experience, they seem to encourage confusing and unmaintainable code. Next time, I would just insert the values directly, as you say.